# Proof that $\exists N\in \Bbb Z^+$ such that $|f(a_n)|\geq \frac{|f(a)|}{3}$ for all $n\gt N$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> Is my proof valid?

---

a
Let $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be a continuous function. Let $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a convergent sequence in $\Bbb R$ with $\lim \limits_{n\to\infty} a_n=a$ and $f(a)\ne 0$.

$\exists N\in \Bbb Z^+$ such that $|f(a_n)|\geq \frac{|f(a)|}{3}$ for all $n\gt N$

---

Proof:

$|a- a_n|\lt \epsilon_1 \implies |f(a)-f(a_n)|\lt\epsilon_2$ by continuity, and thus

Set $\epsilon_2 = \frac{|f(a)|}{3}$, and thus $|f(a)-f(a_n)|\lt\frac{|f(a)|}{3}$

$$-|f(a_n)|\leq |f(a)|-|f(a_n)|\leq |f(a)-f(a_n)|\leq \frac{|f(a)|}{3}$$

and hence $-|f(a_n)|\leq \frac{|f(a)|}{3}\implies |f(a_n)|\geq \frac{|f(a)|}{3}$

Comment: Just write $δ$ in the place of the second $ε$. Otherwise correct.

Comment: @Stef Good?$\quad$

Comment: it is customary(?) to use $\delta$ in place of your $\epsilon_1$ and plain $\epsilon$ for your $\epsilon_2.$ makes for an easier reading to the person who will have to read. if you are looking at the graph of $y = f(n),$ you will draw two lines $y = f(a) \pm \frac 13 |f(a)|.$ the graph of $y=f$ has to get in the band eventually, and stay there afterwards. this is what the statement means.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks @Abel

Comment: you are welcome. go slow and enjoy your math journey.

Comment: @abel I am forced to go slow in R-a since I suck at it :). I will.

Comment: Yes, it is ok now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** this was before the change of the question, with $\varepsilon_1$ and $\varepsilon_2$ instead of the same $\varepsilon$.

The beginning of the proof is not valid: besides the missing quantifiers, continuity does not guarantee at all that it is the same $\varepsilon$ in both sides. The correct statement would be:
"for all $\varepsilon_2 > 0$, there exists a $\varepsilon_1=\varepsilon_1(\varepsilon_2) > 0$ such that $\lvert a - a_n \rvert \leq \varepsilon_1 \Rightarrow \lvert f(a) - f(a_n) \rvert \leq \varepsilon_2$.
Taking $\varepsilon_2=\frac{f(a)}{3}$, we get (...)
"

The rest is correct, besides another small point: once you have established the existence of this quantity $\varepsilon_1$, you need to argue that there is a $N\geq 0$ such that $n \geq N \Rightarrow \lvert a - a_n \rvert \leq \varepsilon_1$. This is easily done by observing that this is exactly what $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = a$ guarantees.

Comment: Ahhh yes the quantifiers, good point, but yes that was a mistake with the same $\epsilon$ that was a typing error

Comment: @Committingtoachallenge See my update. I'll update $\delta$, $\varepsilon$ to match your new notations.

Comment: Sorry what does 'establish the existence of this quantity $\epsilon_1$' mean? Just saying $\epsilon\gt 0$?

Comment: It just means that you know there exists **some** particular $\varepsilon_1 > 0$ such that, for **this** choice of $\varepsilon_2=f(a)/3$, $|a-a_n| \leq \varepsilon_1$ implis $|f(a)-f(a_n)|\leq \varepsilon_2$. It remains to prove that for all sufficiently big $n$ you **do** have $|a-a_n| \leq \varepsilon_1$  for this specific $\varepsilon_1$.

Comment: Isn't that immediately true from the definition of a limit? E.g. $n\gt N \implies |a_n-a|\lt\epsilon$?

Comment: It is -- the whole point is that you still have to explicitly prove/state it, given the question you are asking. Otherwise, the *whole* thing could basically be argued to be "immediate given the definition of a limit and continuity."

Comment: Very very true, thank you so much!